# How can you install ruby on rails on a Windows 8.1 Pro IIS v8.5 x64 site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iis, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an IIS 8.5 server setup that is already being used to develop PHP and JSP applications and I would like to now add ruby on rails support.

I have used the railsinstaller to install ruby, and have run the **rails new [appname]** on rails v4 program to create the application.  The application did not include dispatch.cgi so I grabbed the following off of the net.

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
ENV['HOME'] ||= `echo ~`.strip
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems')
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems')

require 'fcgi'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../config/environment.rb')

flog = File.open('fastcgi.log', 'a+')
STDOUT.reopen flog
STDERR.reopen flog
STDOUT.sync = true
STDERR.sync = true

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
 def initialize(app)
  @app = app
 end

 def call(env)
  env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
  parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
  env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
  env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
  @app.call(env)
 end

end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(Sampleapp::Application)
```

I also created a mapping handler of *.fcgi to run ruby.exe.  The problem I have right now I believe is because rails doesn't come with a fcgi module so the "require 'fcgi'" is failing. The actual error is as follows...

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
```

Running it from the command line I get the following

```
c:\inetpub\rails\railsapp\public>ruby dispatch.fcgi
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
36:in `require': cannot load such file -- fcgi (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from dispatch.fcgi:7:in `<main>'

c:\inetpub\rails\railsapp\public>
```

So how can I install the missing fcgi x64 module for rails, or in some other way get this to run?

Comment: same problem, on windows 7 (iis 7.5) without rails, just erb, no luch until so far, fcgi doesn't get installed